# Python: Providing parameter conversion for lots of functions

Tags: python

Let's say I have a lot of functions that accept input in a certain format.

Let's say I want to offer to the user of my module the option to call those functions with input in another format. Conversion is easy.

I don't feel like doing the conversion inside each individual function, and I feel it'd be bad practice to just do a copy-paste of my functions and then insert the conversion by hand.

I also feel that I shouldn't have to manually go to each function and change it to an *args and **kwargs signature and insert a lot of boilerplate code that says "If one of your kwargs is this, do that, and if it's that, do this".

What's a good approach to this sort of thing? Dynamic function generation plus decorators? Something else entirely?

Comment: Define "format". Why not write one adapter function that does whatever conversions are necessary?

Comment: why would you not do the conversion inside each function? also, I am finding it hard to understand the uses of this and itd be great to have an example of what you mean by different formats and what the functions look like

Comment: @timgeb I have an adapter function but want to shift the burden of calling it from the module's end user to me, the module's developer. Like, let's say internally my module works with graphs in adjacency matrix format but I want to offer function signatures that accept the graph as adjacency list.

Sure I can do the conversion inside each function but that feels like doing a lot of copy & paste and I was wondering if there's a way to do it more elegantly. Maybe through some decorator ala "@conversion"

Comment: @Lagerbaer I still don't understand why the user would have the burden to do the conversion. Why can't your adapter function check for the input format, do the conversion such that your code will understand the format and then call your other functions/Graph class constructor/etc?

Comment: But then I'd still have to write one individual adapted version for each version currently in my library, would I not?

Comment: I think a decorator is a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

You still have to define what to do for each function for different overload of the arguments. At least for sake of definition which signature is overloaded which is not. See code below. **foo** is overloaded and **UnchangedFoo** is not.

Here is example what you can do inspired by [Guido van van Rossum](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=101605)

```
from mm import multimethod

@multimethod(int)
def foo(i):
    ...code for int...

@multimethod(list):
def foo(List):
    for i in List:
       foo(i)

def UnchangedFoo(i):
    ...some code...
```